# How to get checkboxes working with ng-touch?

Tags: angularjs, angular-touch

Forms elements like checkboxes and radio buttons seem to not work with touch libraries like ng-touch. Any workaround or solutions for the same ?

Comment: why you want to use ng-touch,ur exact requirement??

Comment: I am creating a multi-touch app using HTML5- AngularJS, on a touch device on an OS that is neither android nor IOS, hence can't use compilers like phonegap. Also gestures like pinch and zoom are only working with ng-touch.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another directive that simulates a click event to replace `ngTouch`'s `ng-click` version for that specific problem.

```
.directive('basicClick', function($parse, $rootScope) {
 return {
  compile: function(elem, attr) {
    var fn = $parse(attr.basicClick);
    return function(scope, elem) {
     elem.on('click', function(e) {
       fn(scope, {$event: e});
       scope.$apply();
      });
     };
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: The current version of ng-touch already has an ng-click very similar to this. Plus it is not so much with the click that the problem is. Even if the only operation is setting true or false value to a scope variable based on checkbox status using ng-model, the checkbox dosen't seem to work